# How to select Material UI Tab with URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am trying to find a way to control the selected tab with the URL. So far I can set the selected tab when the component loads by doing this in the constructor:

```
    let selectedTab = 0;
    props.layout.map((element, index) => {
        if (element.name === props.startingTab) {
            selectedTab = index;
        }
    })

    this.state = {
        value: selectedTab
    }
```

Layout is an array of objects passed into the tab component that includes which components to display, order to display them in and their display names.

I can also parse the URL when a different tab is clicked and update it correctly by doing this:

```
    const url = this.props.match.url;
    const layout = this.props.layout;
    this.props.history.push(`${url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') +1)}${layout[value].name}`)
```

But neither of these does anyone for a user pressing back, and parsing the URL feels quite clunky.

Is there a better way of doing this? I am using React Router v4 and just native React state for now.

Answer (score 0):

React Router doesn't support `BrowserRouter` + `HashRouter` in the same application. It would work if you set each of the tabs to a separate path using the `href` prop.

Comment: Would using the Link component from React Router be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Link component is used for defined routes. So it should work where your container is rendered by the routes.